# how do I compare 3 numbers in sml?

Tags: comparison, max, sml, ml

I am trying to come up with an function that takes 3 numbers as input and returns the largest number among them. My code is as following:

```
fun max3(a,b,c)=
    if a >= b andalso a >= c then a
    else if b >= a andalso b >= c then b
    else if c >= a andalso c >= b then c;
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
Error: syntax error: inserting  LET
Error: syntax error: replacing  SEMICOLON with EQUALOP
Error: syntax error found at EOF
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Looks like an error with your logic, but the programming language looks strange to me, so it could simply just be the language.

Comment: @cybermonkey, I have just fixed the error I had in the input.However, I still get the errors.

Comment: The inscrutable syntax error messages are probably the worst part of ML programming. It looks like they come from the compiler thinking "if I insert this here, and change that, I can keep going and see what happens", which I've never found useful in any way. In a reasonable world, this one would say "missing 'else' after 'c'" instead of gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have an `if`, you need a `then` and an `else`. You can see how this becomes a problem by changing how you indent things.

```
fun max3(a,b,c)=
    if a >= b andalso a >= c
    then a
    else if b >= a andalso b >= c
         then b
         else if c >= a andalso c >= b
              then c
              (* notice how there is no else here? *)
              ;
```

However, you can simplify the logic a lot:

```
fun max3(a,b,c)=
    if a >= b andalso a >= c then
        (* a is the largest of a, b and c *)
        a
    else
        (* a is not the largest, so either b or c is the largest *)
        if b >= c then
            (* b is the largest of the two *)
            b
        else
            (* c is the largest of the two *)
            c
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce this problem to an already solved one:

```
fun max3 (a, b, c) = max2 (a, max2 (b, c))
```

where

```
fun max2 (a, b) = if a > b then a else b
```

or simply

```
val max2 = Int.max
```